# is there a way to pass this as const?

Tags: c++, class, constants, this

I have **a class of items** and **a function that returns it's size**. 
I have the **operator == which gets 2 const parameters of the class** type and return the result of **item1.size() == item2.size ()**. size function is non-parametres func and need only hidden this parameter.

The problem is when I try to use size on const reference of classes, it's give me an error:

```
'function' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'type1' to 'type2'

The compiler could not convert the this pointer from type1to type2.

This error can be caused by invoking a non-const member function on a const object. Possible resolutions:

    Remove the const from the object declaration.

    Add const to the member function.
```

The piece of code as it is on my problem:

```
bool operator==(const CardDeck& deck1, const CardDeck& deck2){
    if (deck1.size() != deck2.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    //...
}
```

The error:

```
 'unsigned int CardDeck::size(void)' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CardDeck' to 'Cardeck&'
```

If I want that size will get the object as const, I must make it friend and pass the object as const refference or is there a way to tell size get the class type this as constant ???
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you make `CardDeck::size() const`?

Comment: As I understand to make it const means to make it's parameters const, and here it get's only this.  to write const CardDeck::size() only means that the returned value (not by reference but only copy of it) will be const, which doesn't mean anything, am I wrong ?
That's why I asked if there is a way to tell the compiler that this is constant for the method size.

Comment: You make the whole function `const` by adding the `const` keyword after the function declaration but before its body. Nothing to do with return type or parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ error C2662 cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Type' to 'Type &'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068301/c-error-c2662-cannot-convert-this-pointer-from-const-type-to-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you forgot to qualify the `size` member function as const: `size_t size() const { return /* compute/return size */; }`

The alternative is that you really did typo `CardDeck` as `Cardeck` somewhere (the spelling from your error message).